# Make the Devise new user form created with railapps a partial to re use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, railsapps

I've created a new app with the [Rails App composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer) with Devise and Pundit. The composer has created a form to create new users (devise/registrations/new.html.erb) which i would like to make a partial so i can put it on other pages. The form is

```
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>ate_field :date_of_birth, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
```

if i put this into a partial and try to render it on another page i get

```
undefined local variable or method `resource
```

and that's obviously because in my controller i didn't define anything. Problem is i can't find the controller or what `resource` should be in the other controller so that i can re-use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource method you are looking for is located [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L16)

resource seems to be defined by an instance variable with the name of the actual resource you're using devise with.

So, if you use devise for the `users` resource you should define resource as `User.new` on the controller you want to render that partial, and mark it as `helper_method` so it may be used in views, or just define it straight in the helper.

Alternatively, you can just inherit `DeviseController` which already includes the resource definition and other useful methods as well.